Email links from iOS Reminders not working on macOS
When I highlight text in Apple Mail on iOS and share it to Reminders, it creates a reminder with a link to the original email. On iOS, clicking this link successfully opens the original email message.
However, when I try to click the same email link in Reminders on macOS, nothing happens. The link is completely unresponsive.
Does anyone know how to get these email links working properly on macOS?

Is the same email account set up in Mail.app on macOS?
